# The object could not be added to the EntityCollection or EntityReference

Tags: linq-to-entities

DAL.SMSModel.tbl_PagesInModules pm = new DAL.Class.PageInModules().Select(2).First();
        System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection pc = new System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection();
        DAL.SMSModel.OmidPaymakEntities o = new DAL.SMSModel.OmidPaymakEntities();

```
    pc.Add(pm);`
```

and this id my error Help me

The object could not be added to the EntityCollection or EntityReference. An object that is attached to an ObjectContext cannot be added to an EntityCollection or EntityReference that is not associated with a source object.

Answer (score 0):

I am no Linq Expert but I think you should try

```
pc.AddObject(pm)
```